# Design Proper Return response from rest service

Tags: rest

Since rest service uses HTTP codes like 200 or 500
it seems to me like returning JSON form a method is redundant,
I would like to return something like:

```
{"status":true/false,"message":if there was a message it will be here}
```

So if the method was successful - it will return

```
{"status":true,"message":null}
```

If the method was no successful - it will return

```
{"status":false,"message":"there was an exception at line 40"}
```

My question is how do others design the return value from rest method to be informative but not redundant?

Comment: What other REST services have you looked at?

Comment: Its a general question on how to design a simple rest method to return informative data about the operation.

Comment: "how do others"

Answer (score 1):

> Since rest service uses HTTP codes like 200 or 500

HTTP status codes are meta data.  The intended audience for HTTP meta data is comprised of general purpose HTTP components.

In the world wide web, the meta data is intended for browsers, caches, reverse proxies, and so on.  The bespoke details are intended for the user (what went wrong, what remedial actions are available, and so on).

In the world of machine to machine, the meta data is there to make sure that the general purpose libraries do the right thing (for instance, automatically invalidating cached responses when appropriate).  The payload, which is to say the document that you are sending, is still something that you will usually end up tailoring to your specific circumstances.

That said, there are certainly behaviors where it can make sense for the response to some request have *no content* in the message body; and there are of course meta data conventions so that general purpose components can be alerted to that case.

For instance, it is perfectly reasonable for an HTTP server to respond to a `PUT /foo` request with a `204 No Content` response -- "I saved the representation that you delivered to me, and that's all we need to say about it."

(We don't tend to use that sort of approach on the web very often, both because we tend not to use PUT, and because bringing the user to a dead end isn't particularly helpful).